# Use cases of @PatchMapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, http

There is a [RequestMethod](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMethod.html) named **PATCH**.

To use this method, we can define [@PatchMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PatchMapping.html) for a rest endpoint.
As per my understanding, it sounds like partially updating the DB object.

Generally, we use POST or PUT calls to perform save or update. So, still not clear what are exact use cases of PatchMapping and why can't I just use PUT instead of PATCH?

Comment: Patch means, update a part of the data. So if you have a complex data object, but you just update a part of them (some fields for example), and don't want to sent the whole object, you can use path to sign thet this is a partial update.

Comment: How that will be processed at the repo level? We have to saveOrUpdate the whole obj! It would be great if you provide a detailed example.

Comment: I found an example:
https://www.baeldung.com/http-put-patch-difference-spring
But if it is not satisfying to you, please let me know.

Comment: Still confused! How it'll work at the repository level?

Comment: Either you set the field to the entity, or more easier, you can use sql/jpql statement , and fill the fields from the posted data (which contains key:value pairs, where key equals with the db field name). You can create a partial object to, and on service level map it into the entity (but in Java it is lot of coding). There are a lot of ways.

Comment: It would be really great if an example of having REST Endpoint, service, and repo code to understand it better!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> still not clear what are exact use cases of PatchMapping and why can't I just use PUT instead of PATCH?

PUT (defined by [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)) and PATCH (defined by [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)) are two different methods used for a similar purpose: to request that the server make its representation of a resource match the representation on the client.

Imagine, if you would, trying to update a web page provided by a server.  The client first obtains a recent copy of the server's representation:

```
GET /foo
```

and then, using the client's favorite local HTML editor, makes changes to this private copy.  When the client has finished making the changes, we want to send those changes back to the server to be used.

The straight forward way to do this in HTTP is to simply send the entire updated representation back to the server:

```
PUT /foo

<html>....</html>
```

When the representation is very large (compared with the HTTP headers), and the edits are very small (compared to the document), then PUT becomes a somewhat "expensive" way to achieve what ought to be a small thing.

To that end, we might also support PATCH, so that instead of sending the *entire* document, we just send a representation of the changes we made: a patch document.

When the server receives our patch, it loads its own copy of the document, applies the changes described by the patch document, and saves the result.

Thus: the overall use case is the same: remote authoring.  You load a representation of a resource into your HTTP aware document editor, make a few changes, and hit "save", and your editor knows what to do to communicate your edits back to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I'm somehow clear on the use case side. It would be really great if an example of having REST Endpoint, service, and repo code to understand it better!